# Discord bot won't take in a new message

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making this weird kinda discord bot. It displays a set of obstacles, and adds a corresponding key that you need to press to a string. It adds a 'w' for every '...', and an 's' for every '***'. In Discord, the player has to type the correct string in to pass the level. So it all works and displays properly. The call function is '!go', and that displays the level. But it fails me before I can type in the string. I want to know, why is it automatically activating? My message.content function is outside that loop. I think it is because I type '!go' and it doesn't reset my message. Here is the code:

````py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global correct_answerS
  correct_answerS = ""
  obstacleList = []

  for i in range (0, 24):
    randNum = random.randint(1,2)
    if randNum == 1:
      obstacleList.append('...')
      correct_answerS += 'w'
    if randNum == 2:
      obstacleList.append('***')
      correct_answerS += 's'


  if message.content == ('!practice'):
    sky = str("```css\n A     ...     ...      ***    ...```")
    skyembed = discord.Embed(title="!============================!")
    skyembed.add_field(name='When you see three dots, it is a w. When you see 3 asteriks, it is an s.', value = sky)
    await message.channel.send(embed=skyembed)
  if message.content == ('wwsw'):
    await message.channel.send("Success.")

  if message.content == ('!go'):
    randlev = (str("```css\n A     ")) 
    for i in range(0, 24): 
      randlev += (str(obstacleList[i]) + "   ")
    randlev += "```"
    randlevembed = discord.Embed(title="!===============================================!")
    randlevembed.add_field(name='Good luck!', value = randlev)
    await message.channel.send(embed=randlevembed)
    print(correct_answerS)

  if message.content == (correct_answerS):
    await message.channel.send("Success!")
  else:
    await message.channel.send("Fail.")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Ready")
  print(client.user.id)
  print('--------------------------')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='up and away'))

client.run(Token)
````

There is no error message, just as soon as I type '!go', it displays the level and then continually says 'Fail.' until I stop it.
I don't know what to do, any help is just that, helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot is stuck in a loop where it's sending a message, and then processing that message, which causes it to send another message, etc.  You can add a check to the beginning of `on_message` to force it to ignore bot-generated messages:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return 
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think it's seeing its own messages, rather it's stuck thinking that my text for the 'correct_answerS' is '!go', which is obviously not correct.

Comment: @Lionguy7 Bots do receive their own messages by default. You have to correct for it in your own code.

Comment: I added what he said, and it's still not working. It does only print 1 'Fail.', but it still doesn't let me type the correct answer before ending it.